# GLADE / "Add widget as toplevel" on new version

Tags: glade

I want to know where is the menu "Add widget as toplevel" in the new version of glade 3.22 ? 
In the old version it's ok, in new I can't add a widget (for example GTKBox) as toplevel. 
How does this work on the new version?

[Glade Old version 3.14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsM3f.png)

[Glade New version 3.22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPqWl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would say:
First create a "GtkWindow" at top level
Second include a "GtkBox" in that GtkWindow (could be a GtkDialog)
you have it.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you answer but I want more .glade files in order to populate dynamically GTKNotebook pages. If I do with a GTKWindows I can't add the Widget in the GTKNotebook page. A new window open. With the old version if I do a GTKBox as toplevel it works fine in the GTKNotebook page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why, but specifically GtkBin can be added as top-level. I did not manage to find any explanation for this, but it sort of feels intentional.